# How to verify if the checkbox is already clicked or not?

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

[image: Code Snippet]My code doesn't verify if the checkbox is clicked or not. It clicks on the box on each iteration regardless its checked or unchecked.
I tried various ways but none are working throws error as expect values doesn't match. It checks and unchecks subsequently

```
  const checkbox = await element(by.css(locatorValue));
    await browser.wait(until.elementToBeClickable(await checkbox), 30,
            'Unable to locate check box to click .');
    if ( expect(checkbox.isSelected()).toBe(false)) {
        console.log('print bValue...:');
        await browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', checkbox.getWebElement());
        await checkbox.click();
        await expect(checkbox.isSelected()).toBe(true);
    } else {
        await expect(checkbox.isSelected()).toBe(true);
        console.log('already checked');
    }



await checkbox.isSelected().then(async bEnabled => {
    if ((bEnabled.toLocaleString()) === false) {
    await checkbox.click().then(() => {
         console.log('Clicking unchecked boxes : ' + bEnabled);
        browser.driver.sleep(2000);
        browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', checkbox.getWebElement());
        checkbox.click();
    }).catch(error => logger.error(error));
    } else {
         console.log('Checkbox was already clicked : ' + bEnabled);
    }
}).catch(error => logger.error(error));


await checkbox.getAttribute('checked').then ((bValue ) => {
console.log('print bValue...: ' + bValue);
if (bValue === null) {
 console.log('Clicking given check box by index number');
     browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', checkbox.getWebElement());
     checkbox.click();
    browser.driver.sleep(2000);

} else {
     console.log('Check box was already clicked');
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily verify it beforehand with the `isSelected` command.

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isSelected

Try:

```
const isChecked = await checkbox.isSelected();
if (!isChecked) {
    // perform click actions here
} else {
    console.log('Checkbox was already clicked : ' + bEnabled);
}
```

Comment: I tried above different methods. There is no way it will skip if the checkbox is already checked. Sometimes, it doesn't click the unchecked box. Really confuse with this kind of behavior

Comment: I tried this way too but it is behaving very weird. Doesn't seem to go in else part

Answer (score 0):

You can check easily the check box is checked or not

```
        var isChecked_1 = $(this).is(":checked");
        if (isChecked_1) {
              // checked action
        }
        else {
             //  Unchecked action
        }
```

Comment: I have added the code snippet. What I observed, it always return getattribute('checked')  null and isSelected (false) regardless it is checked or unchecked. It never returns true value in any of the case